# Can't find the reason of "IndexOutOfRangeException"

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm getting a weird issue with indexOutOfBounds exception. I need to read the first character of each string in the array.

I get an exception in 5th line (linesRead[i][0]). Weirdest part for me is that when I tried to add lines for debugging Console.WriteLine(linesRead[0][0]) / Console.WriteLine(linesRead[linesRead.Length-1][0]) it works just fine.

```
string[] linesRead = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt"); //Just a bunch of lines

for (int i = 0; i < linesRead.Length; i++)
{
    if (linesRead[i][0] == '5')
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

```
The text inside of test.txt:
5|f-----g-----c---g-----a---|

6|--c-----------------------|
5|---Aa-f-----g-----c-------|

5|------ccdf-ff-----g-----c-|

6|--------------c-----------|
5|--g-----a------Aa-f-----g-|

5|----c-------------ccdf-f--|
```

Comment: What are these lines?  We need a [mcve].  Is one of the lines by chance, empty?

Comment: The first line has to be empty. At least I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: Actually _any_ line being empty will trigger the error.

Comment: There are empty lines in the text you just added. Use the debugger to identify these things. `linesRead[i]` has a value, and you can set a breakpoint in the code and use the watch window to find out what that value is. A few people figured out that at some point, it's an empty string. Lo and behold: Some of your lines are empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (linesRead[i][0] == '5')` will trigger this error if a line is empty.

Try

```
if (linesRead[i].StartsWith("5"))
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would null/empty check each line, just in case.

```cs
var linesRead = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt"); //Just a bunch of lines

foreach (var line in linesRead)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line[0] == '5')
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have an empty line somewhere in your file.

You can skip those lines with:

```
if (linesRead[i].Length > 0 && linesRead[i][0] == '5')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you have an empty string, the character `linesRead[i][0]` is `'\0'` (that's used to mark the end of a string).

If you change your line 5 to `if(linesRead[i].Length > 0 && linesRead[i][0] == '5'))` then you could skip the empty string cases.